# Generated QR image disappers once i exit the application

Tags: java, android, android-widget, qr-code, android-imageview

Recently am being playing around with qr code generation, and after alot of google and help from stack overflow members i was successfully able to generated it, using google API.

but when i click "back" button in the emulator and when i again click theapplication the qr code image disappears??

how to make it stay permanent until i click the "generate" button again for a new Qr image??

here is the code for my question's answer providers and those who are struggling in generation of qr images

```
    package com.test2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test2Activity extends Activity {


     ImageView QRCode;
     TextView MySite;
     EditText text,text1; 
     Button genarate;
     String textbox,textbox2;

       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main);

           QRCode = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.qrimage);
           MySite = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mysite);

           genarate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.genarate);
           genarate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
                text1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text1);
                textbox=text.getText().toString();
                textbox2=text1.getText().toString();
                Bitmap bm = loadQRCode();
                    if(bm == null){
                    Toast.makeText(Test2Activity.this,
                      "Problem in loading QR Code1",
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }else{
                    QRCode.setImageBitmap(bm);
                   }
            }
                    Bitmap loadQRCode(){
                    Bitmap bmQR = null;
                    InputStream inputStream = null;

                    try {
                   inputStream = OpenHttpConnection("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=400x400&cht=qr&chl="+ textbox +"--->"+ textbox2);
                   bmQR = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                   inputStream.close();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                   e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                    return bmQR;
                   }

                   private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
                    InputStream is = null;
                    URL url = new URL(strURL);
                    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

                    try{
                     HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConnection;
                     httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                     httpConn.connect();

                     if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                      is = httpConn.getInputStream(); 
                     }
                     }catch (Exception ex){
                     }

                    return is; 
                 }  
        });
       }
    }
```

xml code for this activity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/genarate"
    android:layout_width="97dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="genarate" />

<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/qrimage"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:saveEnabled="true" android:visibility="visible"/>

<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/mysite"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the generated image as a [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) string in your [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

To encode the image do something like: `Base64.encode(image, Base64.DEFAULT)`.

To store and retrieve values from your SharedPreferences you can use in your Activity:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);   

//Save String
preferences.edit().putString("image64", imageData).commit();

//Get String
String imageBase64 = preferences.getString("image64", null);
                                                       ^----- Default value
if(imageBase64 == null)
    Log.d("LOG", "No image stored in the SharedPreferences");

//Create a bitmap from the base64 data
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: friend am a noob with shared preferences, if u can alter by above java code with the code u suggest and post it below, it would be a great help for me

Comment: friend i changed the code this way, but still after i exit and enter it disappears `if(bm == null){ Toast.makeText(Test2Activity.this, "Problem in loading QR Code1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }else{ QRCode.setImageBitmap(bm); String imageBase64 = preferences.getString("QRCode", null); preferences.edit().putString("QRCode", imageBase64).commit(); }`

Comment: What is the `bm` you are checking in your `if`?

Comment: that is the thing we are saving in the shared preferences friend

Comment: friend hope so i confused the code a bit, shall i mail u this project workspace so that u can correct this error and mail me??

Comment: I just edited my answer so you can convert the image in base64 to a bitmap so you can set it on your layout.. but remember to check first if you saved any picture in there.. and put that code outside the `onClick` event as you want it when the application loads.. not when the user clicks.. when the click events happen is when you have to store the bitmap on your sharedPrefs

Comment: friend i try my best, but i failed, shall i mail u my project workspace , so that u can correct in minutes and mail me back